# Is it possible to change a Virtual Key code?

Tags: key, hex, virtual

I want to try and swap some keyboard keys. Say for example the home key has the hex value of 0x24. Is it possible to replace that value with something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interestingly enough, keyboard input on Windows is handled in a very complicated sort of way. Keystrokes have target applications (referred to as sinks) and if a particular sink doesn't handle something then it has to "bubble up" to it's owner (which in most cases is either the window that created it or the desktop). That being said, you can programmatically receive keystrokes and send keystrokes, but this introduces two complexities. First, your app needs to be the first thing to receive input all the time, unless you want unreliable control. Secondly, you need to have a target for your keystroke (ie another window has to have focus while your app processes their keystrokes) which is weird. So yes, it is possible, but feasible, probably not.